# Draw a Hand Signature in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, blackberry-playbook

I am creating an application that requires a user to draw their hand signature on a tablet. Does anyone the best way to do this on Flex mobile 4.5? What do I draw on to, a Sprite, canvas?

Also, I would need to save the signature as a .jpg, could this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look on the following:

http://www.jamesward.com/2010/03/22/flex-paint-updated-to-flex-4/

It may give you some hints.

Comment: P.s. You can use the JPGEncoder to encode the image for saving.  (The example has png).

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry-provided [sample signature capture app](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/Signature-Capture-Sample-Code/ta-p/1184541) ought to be a good starting point.