# Electronic Signature in Flex Mobile Application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, ipad, tablet

The current mobile application I am developing in Flex calls for a client to be able to electronic sign a signature box in a document with their finger (This is a tablet application). Does anyone know of a good way to accomplish this in a Flex Mobile Application?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this post and that no one had answered it yet, so I'm taking it by storm. [Here is a scribbling/signature example I cooked up for you.](http://jacksonkr.com/content/signature-pad) It's written with *Flash*, but the **as3 will work in Flex** just the same. I didn't have *"Flash Builder"* installed on my home computer or I would have done this in *Flex* (sad face).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the following:

http://www.jamesward.com/2010/03/22/flex-paint-updated-to-flex-4/

It may give you some hints.

similar to:
[Draw a Hand Signature in Flex 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734898/draw-a-hand-signature-in-flex-4/6735080#6735080)